# how to print array of objects's key value in my existing div & repeat it based on my data for each separate div with JavaScript with loop

Tags: javascript

i have create a array of objects in JavaScript and now want to show each objects's key value in my existing div having class with loop function.

i also want to iterate my div DOM creation based on my object length.

```js
let myObj = [
  {
    name: 'rajvir',
    age: 40,
    profession: 'IT'
  },
  {
    name: 'rajvir2',
    age: 30,
    profession: 'IT2'
  },
  {
    name: 'rajvir3',
    age: 35,
    profession: 'IT3'
  }
]
let objRow = document.getElementById('objRow');
for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('objRow').innerHTML = myObj[i].name;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<div>
<p id="objRow">
<span id="name"></span>
<span id="age"></span>
<span id="profession"></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use template literals and iterate the array of objects using for each

```js
let myObj = [{
    name: 'rajvir',
    age: 40,
    profession: 'IT'
  },
  {
    name: 'rajvir2',
    age: 30,
    profession: 'IT2'
  },
  {
    name: 'rajvir3',
    age: 35,
    profession: 'IT3'
  }
]
let objRow = document.getElementById('objRow');

let result = '';
myObj.forEach((item) => {

  result += `<div><span>${item.name}</span>
             <span>${item.age}</span>
             <span>${item.profession}</span></div>`
})

objRow.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<pre>
<div>
<p id="objRow"></p>
</div>

<pre>
```

Comment: Thanks brk!! you have give me shorter & flexible solution. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObj = [
  { name: 'rajvir', age: 40, profession: 'IT' },
  { name: 'rajvir2', age: 30, profession: 'IT2' },
  { name: 'rajvir3', age: 35, profession: 'IT3' }
]
let objRow = document.getElementById('objRow');
for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
   objRow.innerHTML += i +" = "+ myObj[i].name + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<pre>
<div>
<p id="objRow">
<span id="name"></span>
<span id="age"></span>
<span id="profession"></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
let myObj = [
                {
                    name: 'rajvir',
                    age: 40,
                    profession: 'IT'
                },
                {
                    name: 'rajvir2',
                    age: 30,
                    profession: 'IT2'
                },
                {
                    name: 'rajvir3',
                    age: 35,
                    profession: 'IT3'
                }
            ]
            let objRowDiv = document.getElementById('objRowDiv');
            for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
                let objRow = document.createElement("p");
                objRow.innerHTML = ('<span id="name">'+myObj[i].name+'</span> | <span id="age">'+myObj[i].age+'</span> | <span id="profession">'+myObj[i].profession+'</span>');
                objRowDiv.append(objRow);
            }
```

```html
<pre>
    <div id="objRowDiv">
    </div>
<pre>
```